# Java Generics - Compile time validation of type and implementing object

Tags: java, generics

I have a method to add implementing class' objects against interface class and I want to make this as a generic one.
The implementing class also extends a class X

```
public abstract class X<T>{...}

public interface InterfaceA{...}

public class A extends X implements InterfaceA{...}
```

now, currently my method is:

```
public <S, <T extends X<S>> void add(Class<S> clazz, T object){...}
```

But I have no use of type parameter on X, it is just for the above method. Is there a way I could have X without type parameter and still have compile-time validation in method 'add' please?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I think my question is not clear. Please look at the below example code:

```
public interface I {}

public abstract class X {}

public class A extends X implements I {}

public class B implements I {}

public class C extends X {}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        add(I.class, new A());  // uses first method
        add(I.class, new B());  // uses second method
        add(I.class, new C());  // uses first method
    }

    public static <P, T extends P> void add(Class<P> c, T object) {}  //No

    public static <P, T extends X> void add(Class<P> c, T object) {}  //No

}
```

I need an 'add' method that just accepts A's instance and not B's not C's.
Both the above method signature don't fulfill my requirement

Comment: Presumably if `X`is declared with a type parameter (`X<T>`) then `T` is used within `X`.  There isn't enough context in your question to understand what you mean by _"have `X` without type parameter "_ or why that is needed.

Comment: 'add' method must accept an interface class as first param, and its implementation as second parameter. So, it is just for the 'add' method to verify the type (in `<T extends X<S>>` part). Right now, the add method works perfectly. Only thing is I added bloat Type T to X to make this work.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have updated my question with a case. Could you please help?

Comment: The statement `add(I.class, new A());` does not use the first method. It is ambiguous according to Eclipse.  Either of the `add` methods could apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the type parameter of `X`, just make it `Object`:

```
public class A extends X<Object> implements InterfaceA{...}
```

So the method will work with anything.

Comment: I want something like `public static <P, T extends X & P> void add(Class<P> c, T object) {}` - Of course this one is wrong

Comment: @Gurwinder the problem is you can't specify that a type is bounded by an interface. Can you just have name the methods differently to work around the ambiguity?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can remove the type on X and still get a compile-time error for add in the following manner. Now, of course, a little more context will be more helpful if this doesn't meet your requirement.

```
public abstract class X {
}

public class A<T> extends X implements InterfaceA {

      public <S, M extends X> void add(Class<S> clazz, M object){
      }

      public void abc() {
         Class<String> clazz = String.class;
         this.add(clazz, new B());//This should throw compilation error
      }

}

public class B implements InterfaceA {
}
```